# Moyal brackets / quantum Liouville equation for non-Wigner representations?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics

For a [Wigner-Ville quasi-probability distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_quasi-probability_distribution) $W(q,p,t)$ and Hamiltonian $H(q,p)$, we can write a quantum Liouville equation:

$\frac{\partial W(q,p,t)}{\partial t} = -\{\{W(q,p,t) , H(q,p )\}\}$

where $\{\{a, b\}\}$ is the [Moyal bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moyal_bracket).  This comes from applying a Wigner transformation to the Von Neumann equation for density matrices.  Are there similar, clean-looking, quantum Liouville equations for the evolution of the [Glauber-Sudarshan P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glauber_P_representation), the [Husimi Q](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Husimi_Q_representation), or other representations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer to this offline.  The answer is that the form looks the same for all representations with a suitable redefinition of the star product.  For example, in the Husimi Q representation, we can define a new kind of star product as follows:

$
f\circledast g= f \exp \left ( {{\frac{\hbar }{2}}(\stackrel{\leftarrow }{\partial }_x
\stackrel{\rightarrow }{\partial }_{p}+\stackrel{\leftarrow }{\partial }_{p}\stackrel{\rightarrow }{\partial }_{x})} \right ) \star g = f \exp \left ( {{\frac{\hbar }{2}}(\stackrel{\leftarrow }{\partial }_x-i\stackrel{\leftarrow }{\partial }_{p})(\stackrel{\rightarrow }{\partial }_x+i\stackrel{\rightarrow }{\partial }_{p})} \right ) g
$

If $T$ is the map from Wigner to Husimi, then this product has the following property:

$
T(f \star g) = T(f) \circledast T(g)
$

Therefore the quantum Liouville equation in the Husimi representation is

$
\frac{\partial Q}{\partial t} = - \frac{1}{i\hbar} (Q \circledast H - H \circledast Q)
$

See e.g. [this reference](http://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/a.pdf).